# Podman on mac error : connect: no such file or directory

Tags: podman

Installed Podman for mac with brew

```
brew install podman
```

It's installed successfully, but then if you try to use it with something like

```
podman images
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Get "http://d/v2.0.0/libpod/_ping": dial unix ///var/folders/x2/j64rkhwn7gvghnmcz2h_nh080000gn/T/podman-run--1/podman/podman.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

Cannot seem to find a solution in documentation, has anyone had the same issue and any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to run:

```
podman machine init
podman machine start
```

Comment: This worked for me. Should this be the accepted answer?

Comment: I'm having issue when I've have initialised and started the machine. Then I've turned off the podman machine, restarted mac, and tried podman machine start to only see that connection refused error.

Comment: After a bit of searching, looks like I probably found the issue. When creating a podman machine with more than 3GB memory (by default it allocates 2GB), it fails to start that machine (as mentioned in this [discussion](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14303)). I've now created a machine with default memory allocation and it's starting now.

Answer (score 1):

In the Firewall pane of Security & Privacy preferences

- Allow "podman-remote" to accept incoming network connections, generally located `/usr/local/bin/podman-remote`
- Allow "gvproxy" to accept incoming network connections, generally located at
  `/usr/local/Cellar/podman/$PODMAN_VERSION/libexec/gvproxy`